# Snap.svg : Can't animate object

Tags: animation, snap.svg

I am trying to animate an object with snap.svg, it's showing but not scaling. 
Here's my code.
It works only if I generate the object with code but not working with loaded svg objects.
Why it's not being animated on hover?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snap.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #svg {
            width : 600px;
            height : 600px;
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <svg id="svg"> </svg>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var paper = Snap("#svg");
    Snap.load("balls.svg" , function(d){
        var icon = d.select('#round_ball');
        var back = d.select('#background');
        paper.append(d);

        back.attr({
            fill : '#000000'
        });

        icon.hover(function(event) {

            this.animate({
                transform : "t110,150",
                filter: f 
            }, 200, mina.easeout);


        }, function(event) {
            this.animate({
                transform : "t0,0"
            }, 200, mina.easeout);
        });

    });

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the svg doc

Comment: Is the 'filter: f' supposed to be there? (just asking - new to snap.svg)